# Padding/marging with footer

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, footer

As you can see on my website (http://student.howest.be/marnik.bruyndonckx/eindopdrachtweb/Musea)
I'm missing some padding/margin to have some space between the image and the footer.

This strange due to the fact that on a few other pages (http://student.howest.be/marnik.bruyndonckx/eindopdrachtweb/Winkelen) there IS a space between the image and the footer, and ofcourse it's the same .css file

Comment: I suggest you to use `<table>` ;).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution:

```
footer {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below styles also to footer style

```
footer {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `<div style="clear: both"></div>` just before footer, like you are using it after header. Or move that second image to second `<p>`.